# How to resolve shared library location when it changes between compile & run time?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, gnu-make

I have the following:

```
g++ $(LD_OPTS) -o lib/foo.so lib/bar.o lib/qaz.o ../path/to/foodependency.so
```

It and `foo` are both being built here (assume foodependency has already been built by the makefile previously). The end result looks something like this, during build:

```
project
---libFoo
------lib
---------foo.so
---libFooDependency
------lib
---------foodependency.so
```

However, during runtime, both foo.so and foodependency.so are in the same directory, `bar`:

```
bar
---foo.so
---foodependency.so
```

This layout during runtime cannot be changed. But now as a result, `ldd foo.so` returns the following:
`../path/to/foodependency.so => not found`

How can I resolve this difference?

Comment: Use `-L<path>` and `-l<barename>`?

Comment: @EtanReisner `l<barename>` wouldn't work if the library is called `foodependency.so` (without `lib` in the name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I resolve this

There are several ways.

1. Rename `foodependency.so` to `libfoodependency.so`, and use `-L../path/to -lfoodependency` when linking, or
2. Use `-L../path/to -l:foodependency.so` when linking, or
3. When linking `foodependency.so`, add `-Wl,--soname=foodependency.so` and use your original link line.